What voltages do rack mount audio equipment use?
i am an electronics engineering student looking to work on analog audio equipment for studios. Can anyone please tell me what kinds of signaling voltage do these blocks use?
PC -> patch bay -> compressor -> patch bay -> PC
I'm interested about the audio signal's voltage between the patch bay and the compressor on both the input and the output side of the equipment.
I'm very early into my learning of these things and have only designed compressors and drum circuits to know how they are made ignoring all the voltage level norms[i used +12-12V lines for my learning circuit designs].
Now that i want to make these circuits actually work and usable with normal audio setups, these audio levels are really messing me up with contrasting information from everyone.
Sweetwater says pro line audio is +-1.24V but i've seen people talk about +15-15V as well.
As a student looking to make his first equipment and write his first research paper on the same, i would really like some help {I'm an Indian student and audio electronics being a sufficiently niche topic finds no professors or industries working on it}
Side-note:
I've designed a mixed signal compressor which does some part of the processing analog and does some part of it digitally and combines the two to get some great results; it has been mostly designed for vocals;
Thanks to whoever helps me out.

+-12V  and 15V sound like supply voltages, not audio signal voltages. Think about it: where would you in the end use such gigantic voltages?

What do you mean by signaling voltage?

@MarcusMüller my theory is that opamps can swing upto close to their rail supply voltages. So since I am using +-12V instead of 5V or 3.3V that means my input or any part of the processing involves 12V or 15V or whatever that rail V is.

but that makes no sense – the supply is there for the opamps, not the other way around.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@MarcusMüller suppose i want to buffer a 7Vpp sin wave, then if i use a 5Vpp supply to the opamp then the objective can't be achieved right?
So my question boils down to the point that what is the minimum supply voltage that i can get away with without saturating my op-amps in question.
I'm so sorry for making this complicated.

@Andyaka I mean what voltage PP does the patch bay use to communicate the audio signal to my module.

"Line level" for audio signals is roughly 1 Vrms.1 This would give you ±1.4 V peaks for sine waves. However, audio signals for music tend to be quite "peaky", so power supplies of ±12 V or ±15 V are frequently used to provide sufficient headroom to handle such signals without clipping.

1 The original definition for "0 dBm", where the "m" denotes "milliwatt", was "1 mW into 600 Ω", which works out to 0.7746 Vrms, or ±1.1 V peaks for sine waves. Even though nobody uses 600 Ω circuits any more, the voltage level has been retained as a standard, and is denoted by the symbols dBu ("dBm unloaded") or dBV ("dB voltage reference"). Professional audio gear normally runs at a nominal line level of +4 dBu, or 1.228 Vrms.

It's called dBu for lines levels.

This seems like a very fair and well informed ans with the main takeaway being that I should expect an input of 1V RMS for my input at 0db but keep headroom so that louder inputs don't saturate my circuit; and for the output I should keep the same 1v level references.

In a previous job, I designed professional audio gear in the form of STLs (studio-to-transmitter links) that radio stations could use to connect their audio over standard digital telephone lines (T1 lines). We had to pay attention to details like these.

really interesting to know that @DaveTweed.
